# HttpClient returns weird Id from WebAPI | Angular + .net Core

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, angular-httpclient

I made request from Angular 6 to .net Core Api.
But instead of normal Id - I have werid Id
[image]

Can't explain especially that rest data are returns correctly. And result directly in controller API looks fine
[image]

Notice that Main Object shouldn't have any Id property. But API returned, why? On screen it's `rIB71TsfP5rbBl00QVi8`.

My method for getting those data is simple:

```
get<T>(url: string): Observable<T> {
    return this.http.get<T>(this.apiUrl + url);
}
```

I don't know why I cannot reproduce it here...
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rjvat4?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: get(url: string): Observable<T> {  return this.http.get<T>(this.apiUrl + url);}...check your server

Comment: @puntanet What do you mean?

Comment: Try hitting the api directly from the browser (or curl or wget), and see what the api is producing. It's possible, but unlikely that the Angular code is the problem.

Comment: @DiPix I think he means post the server code for the endpoint you are hitting.

Comment: try to remove <T> after the get ... but I think the problem is on the server...and post your component

Comment: API returns correct result. I checked via postman. 
Removing <T> didn't help.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to create a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/angular)?

Comment: Try removing <T> after both get's, then make the Observable an Observable of <any>.

Comment: That's crazy...
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rjvat4?file=src/app/app.component.ts
Here works fine :/

Comment: Haahahah. Could be an issue with your API. But I think the issue is with <T> there. This `T` denotes the `Type` of Observable your method will return. I'm sure you won't be having any <T> types over there. So this isn't really required.  Please make sure to check here with your real API that you're using for your App.

Comment: Omg... I found problem. Some other lib `ng-material-multilevel-menu` overwrite that Id...

Comment: Good to read you found the answer yourself. Please answer your own question to "close" this question.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. Some other lib `ng-material-multilevel-menu` overwrite that Id...